# STM32F302 Nucleo - I2C no clock

Tags: stm32, i2c

I'm trying to use the I2C interface of the STM32F3 Nucleo-Board to communicate with a EEPROM.

Unfortunately I don't have a clock signal. 
I tried to get a clock signal by setting the bits in the registers and also by using CubeMX. Both times I've got the same result: no clock signal.

Thanks for your help!

Here my code...

```
void I2C_Init(void){

RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN;
RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOBEN;

GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER15_1; 
GPIOA->MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODER15_0; //AF
GPIOB->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER7_1; 
GPIOB->MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODER7_0;  //AF

GPIOA->OTYPER |= GPIO_OTYPER_OT_15;
GPIOB->OTYPER |= GPIO_OTYPER_OT_7;    //Open drain

GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= (GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR15_0 | GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR15_1);  //speed high
GPIOB->OSPEEDR |= (GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR7_0 | GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR7_1);

GPIOA->PUPDR &= ~(GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR15_0 | GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR15_1);
GPIOB->PUPDR &= ~(GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR7_0 | GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR_1);  //no pull -> external pull up resistor used

PA15_AF4();
PB7_AF4();  //alternate function 4 used

RCC->CFGR3 |= (1<<I2C1SW);              //SYSCLK
RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_I2C1EN;     //clock enable

I2C1->TIMINGR = 0x10707DBC;  //with CubeMX

I2C1->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_PE;            //peripheral enable

}
```

I use PA15 for SCL and PB7 for SDA.

Comment: `PA15_AF4()` `PB7_AF4()` are magic and non standard. Please just use the HAL library. You already generated code using cubemx. Also what happens if you just use the default SDA and SCL GPIOs

Comment: Hope you don't expect the clock to be present without issuing any master request on the bus (as there is no code of any communication attempt)

Comment: See comment of question author (Steffi) below the only answer: Apparently, the original question has not been fully analysed but in the end the problem was something different. Question seems obsolete now, and further clarification unlikely to come - I'm voting to close it. The uncompleted Q&A won't help other readers.

Answer (score 0):

I2C will only generate a clock on the line if it is sending or expecting data. Try sending data and then using a scope to probe the data and clock line.

Comment: Thakn you!
I had a problem with my EEPROM but now it works

Comment: Does this mean the question is obsolete? As analysis has been aborted, I don't see how this question will help other readers ==> close it?